# How to sort multiple integers without making them array or list in Python

Tags: python

Im just learning programming and I ve picked up Python for start. I have this task to make:
Simulate game with 4 players. Each player is throwing a dice until 6 is thrown, then next player proceedes to throw. Player who throws 6 in most tries is winner. Program should write who player was throwing and how many tries did he get. If 2 players throw 6 on same count of tries the player who was throwing earlier wins.

Task is from pythonladies BTW, currently im stuck sorting tries in descending order and picking the winner. I dont want to put in many conditions (if, ifelse) and also Im on chapter 5 and I didnt learn arrays/lists so I want to make it withou using it. Here is my code so far:

**hrac means player

pokusy means tries**

```
from random import randrange, random

hrac1 = 0
pokusy1 = 0

hrac2 = 0
pokusy2 = 0

hrac3 = 0
pokusy3 = 0

hrac4 = 0
pokusy4 = 0

while hrac4 != 6:
    while True:
        if hrac1 != 6:
            hrac1 = randrange(1, 7)
            pokusy1 = pokusy1 + 1
            print("Hráč 1 hodil: ", hrac1, " Toto bol jeho: ",pokusy1," pokus")
        else:<br>
            break
    while True:<br>
        if hrac2 != 6:
            hrac2 = randrange(1, 7)
            pokusy2 = pokusy2 + 1
            print("Hráč 2 hodil: ", hrac2, " Toto bol jeho: ",pokusy2," pokus")
        else:
            break
    while True:<br>
        if hrac3 != 6:
            hrac3 = randrange(1, 7)
            pokusy3 = pokusy3 + 1
            print("Hráč 3 hodil: ", hrac3, " Toto bol jeho: ",pokusy3," pokus")
        else:
            break
    while True:
        if hrac4 != 6:
            hrac4 = randrange(1, 7)
            pokusy4 = pokusy4 + 1
            print("Hráč 4 hodil: ", hrac4, " Toto bol jeho: ",pokusy4," pokus")
        else:
            break
```

Also if you have and idea to simplify this code Id be glad :)

Comment: You don't need to sort to keep track of the max. Also, if you know about functions, you can simplify your code by writing a function which simulates rolling a die until a 6 is rolled and then returning the number of rolls required. That will cut down on code repetition.

Comment: May I ask you how do you get the biggest number then?

Also thanks for the tip with dice will try! :)

Comment: Initialize the max to a value like -1. Compare each new value with the current max. If the new value is greater than the current max, update the max. After all 4 variables are processed, it will hold the max of those 4 variables.

Comment: Alternatively (and perhaps a bit better). Initialize the max with the first variable and then compare each subsequent value with this max, updating the max as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't know about the lists and arrays then i can tell you the solution from old times when i was a C++ programmer :)

lets imagine these sample numbers for the number of tries:

```
pokusy1 = 1
pokusy2 = 2
pokusy3 = 3
pokusy4 = 4

temp = 0
```

then you just need to compare them in this way:

```
if(pokusy1 > pokusy2):
    temp = pokusy1
else:
    temp = pokusy2
if(pokusy3 > temp):
    temp = pokusy3
if(pokusy4 > temp):
    temp = pokusy4
```